# search for elements in a list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a leader board with two lists which toggle. When I press weekly scorecard - weekly list is displayed and when I press overall Scorecard, overall is displayed.
Just for reference, it works a bit like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pvwvdgLn/1/

My list has 1000 employees.

The problem is that the search box, which is used here to search for an employee in the list, does not work.
I am trying to find a way to search for an employee in the list.

Here is an image of my leader board:
[pic for the leader board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l4ER.png)

I am echoing the list in the leader board from my DB so the link is constantly changing as this is how leader boards are supposed to be.

**php involved with the leaderboard :**

```html
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="weeklylb" class="leadboardcontent">
        <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">
        <ol id = "myOL">
        <mark>
        <?php
            $sql11 = "SELECT *
            FROM pointsBadgeTable
            WHERE WeekNumber ='week04'
            ORDER BY pointsRewarded desc";

           if(($stmt1221 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql11)) != false){
             do {
               while ($row1221 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1221, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                 $resultt[] = $row1221;
               }
             } while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt1221));
             foreach($resultt as $row1221){
               // echo '<li><mark data-id="'.$row1221['EmployeeID'].'">'. $row1221['EmployeeName'].'</mark><small>"'.$row1221['pointsRewarded'].'</small></li>';
               echo  "<li><mark data-id='".$row1221['EmployeeID']."' class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $row1221['rank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $row1221['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $row1221['pointsRewarded'] . "</span></mark></li>";
               // echo  "<div data-id='".$row1221['EmployeeID']."' class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $row1221['rank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $row1221['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $row1221['pointsRewarded'] . "</span></div>";
             }
           //  var_dump($resultt);
            } else {
            echo 'sql error';
            }
        ?>
        </mark>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <svg style="display: none;">
    <symbol id="cup" x="0px" y="0px" width="25px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 25 26" enable-background="new 0 0 25 26" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="#F26856" d="M21.215,1.428c-0.744,0-1.438,0.213-2.024,0.579V0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865H6.69
              C6.204,0,5.81,0.387,5.81,0.865v1.142C5.224,1.641,4.53,1.428,3.785,1.428C1.698,1.428,0,3.097,0,5.148
              C0,7.2,1.698,8.869,3.785,8.869h1.453c0.315,0,0.572,0.252,0.572,0.562c0,0.311-0.257,0.563-0.572,0.563
              c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865c0.421,0,0.816-0.111,1.158-0.303
              c0.318,0.865,0.761,1.647,1.318,2.31c0.686,0.814,1.515,1.425,2.433,1.808c-0.04,0.487-0.154,1.349-0.481,2.191
              c-0.591,1.519-1.564,2.257-2.975,2.257H5.238c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865v4.283c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865h14.525
              c0.485,0,0.88-0.388,0.88-0.865v-4.283c0-0.478-0.395-0.865-0.88-0.865h-1.452c-1.411,0-2.385-0.738-2.975-2.257
              c-0.328-0.843-0.441-1.704-0.482-2.191c0.918-0.383,1.748-0.993,2.434-1.808c0.557-0.663,1-1.445,1.318-2.31
              c0.342,0.192,0.736,0.303,1.157,0.303c0.486,0,0.88-0.387,0.88-0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865
              c-0.315,0-0.572-0.252-0.572-0.563c0-0.31,0.257-0.562,0.572-0.562h1.452C23.303,8.869,25,7.2,25,5.148
              C25,3.097,23.303,1.428,21.215,1.428z M5.238,7.138H3.785c-1.116,0-2.024-0.893-2.024-1.99c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99
              c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99v2.06C5.627,7.163,5.435,7.138,5.238,7.138z M18.883,21.717v2.553H6.118v-2.553H18.883
              L18.883,21.717z M13.673,18.301c0.248,0.65,0.566,1.214,0.947,1.686h-4.24c0.381-0.472,0.699-1.035,0.947-1.686
              c0.33-0.865,0.479-1.723,0.545-2.327c0.207,0.021,0.416,0.033,0.627,0.033c0.211,0,0.42-0.013,0.627-0.033
              C13.195,16.578,13.344,17.436,13.673,18.301z M12.5,14.276c-2.856,0-4.93-2.638-4.93-6.273V1.73h9.859v6.273
              C17.43,11.638,15.357,14.276,12.5,14.276z M21.215,7.138h-1.452c-0.197,0-0.39,0.024-0.572,0.07v-2.06
              c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99C23.241,6.246,22.333,7.138,21.215,7.138z" />
</div>
        <!-- weekly div ends -->
<div id="overalllb" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">

<div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">
<ol id = "myOL">

 <mark>

   <?php
   $q4 = "select *
   from EmployeeTable
   order by Total_points_Rewarded desc";

if(($stmt33 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $q4)) != false){
 do {
   while ($row333 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt33, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $resulttt[] = $row333;
   }
 } while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt33));
 foreach($resulttt as $row333){
   // echo '<li><mark data-id="'.$row1221['EmployeeID'].'">'. $row1221['EmployeeName'].'</mark><small>"'.$row1221['pointsRewarded'].'</small></li>';
echo  "<li><mark data-id='".$row333['EmployeeID']."' class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $row333['overallRank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $row333['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $row333['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</span></mark></li>";
// echo  "<div data-id='".$row1221['EmployeeID']."' class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $row1221['rank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $row1221['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $row1221['pointsRewarded'] . "</span></div>";
 }
//  var_dump($resultt);
} else {
 echo 'sql error';
}

?>
</mark>
</ol>
  </div>
  <!-- leaderboard div ends here of overall-->

</div>
<!-- overall div ends here -->



</div>
```

**html associated with search box :**

```html
<div id="search5back">

      <form method="get" action="/search" id="searchbox5">
      <input id="search52" name="q" type="text" size="40" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search an Employee ...." />
      </form>

      </div>
```

**Javascript that I have tried :**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ol, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("search52");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ol = document.getElementById("myOL");
  li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
  divs=li[0].getElementsByClassName("parent-div");
  for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      a = divs[i].getElementsByClassName("name")[0];
      if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          divs[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
          divs[i].style.display = "none";
      }
  }
}
```

The search-box needs to work for both the list in the leader board. I believe the `ol` with an id of `id="myol"` needs to be different for both the list.

Comment: Would you mind to reformat your posted source code? A horizontal scrollbar does not improve the readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is `divs=li[0].getElementsByClassName("parent-div");` class parent-div doesnt exisit and more over idea is to iterate over text in li mark tag.

```
function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, ol, li, a, i;
      input = document.getElementById("search52");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      if(document.getElementById('overalllb').style.display=="none")
        ol = document.getElementById("myOL");
      else
        ol = document.getElementById("myOLoverAll");
      li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");

      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
          a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("mark")[0];
          if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              li[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
              li[i].style.display = "none";
          }
      }
    }
```

And for individual search in tab, you need to provide different ids to ol and check which is active in `myFunction()`;

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/pvwvdgLn/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot.Works perfect.